# Get CMake to not be silent about sources it doesn't understand?

Tags: cmake

[Suppose you have a very simple CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/mgaudet/cmake_silent_drop)

```
add_executable(silent T.cpp A.asm)
```

CMake will happily generate a C++ target for building `silent`, with `T.cpp` in it, but will silently drop any and all reference to `A.asm`, because it doesn't know what to do with the suffix.

Is there any way to get CMake to loudly complain about this source file it doesn't understand (to aid in porting a Makefile to CMake).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring unknown file extensions is - unfortunately for your case - by design.

If I look at the code of [`cmGeneratorTarget::ComputeKindedSources()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.13.0/Source/cmGeneratorTarget.cxx#L1088) anything unknown ends up to be classified as `SourceKindExtra` (to be added as such to generated IDE files).

So I tested a little and came up with the following script that evaluates your executable target source files for valid file extensions by overwriting `add_executable()` itself:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(silent CXX)

file(WRITE T.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")
file(WRITE T.h "")
file(WRITE A.asm "")

function(add_executable _target)
    _add_executable(${_target} ${ARGN})

    get_property(_langs GLOBAL PROPERTY ENABLED_LANGUAGES)
    foreach(_lang IN LISTS _langs)
        list(APPEND _ignore "${CMAKE_${_lang}_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS}")
    endforeach()

    get_target_property(_srcs ${_target} SOURCES)
    foreach(_src IN LISTS _srcs)
        get_source_file_property(_lang "${_src}" LANGUAGE)
        get_filename_component(_ext "${_src}" EXT)
        string(SUBSTRING "${_ext}" 1 -1 _ext) # remove leading dot
        if (NOT _lang AND NOT _ext IN_LIST _ignore)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Target ${_target}: Unknown source file type '${_src}'")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()

add_executable(silent T.cpp T.h A.asm)
```

Since you wanted a rather loudly complain by CMake I declared it an `FATAL_ERROR` in this example implementation.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

CMake doesn't just drop unknown files in `add_executable()`.

If alongside with

```
add_executable(silent T.cpp A.asm)
```

you have

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT A.asm COMMAND <...>
    DEPENDS <dependees>)
```

then whenever `<dependees>` changed CMake will rerun command for create `A.asm` before compiling the executable.

Note, that *automatical headers scanning* doesn't provide such functionality: if your executable includes `foo.h` then executable will be rebuilt only when `foo.h` **itself** is changed. Any custom command creating this header will be *ignored*.

---

However, you may *change* behavior of `add_executable` by redefining it. See @Florian's answer for example of such redefinition.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks so much. That's a helpful piece of info here.